# How to detect build config in VS and use that info with cmake interpreter?

Tags: visual-studio, cmake

I have to use `ExternalProject_Add` that takes different parameters depending on the build configuration (debug vs release). It will also produce libraries with different names, etc.. It means that `CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE` is never defined.

On OS where I use `make` there are no issues because `-DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=` will do the job, but when building with VS on Windows cmake is pretty shitty.

Is there a solution for that problem?

Comment: Many parameters to `ExternalProject_Add` supports [generator-expressions](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-generator-expressions.7.html), which are the proper way for express build-dependent settings in case of multiconfiguration [generator](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-generators.7.html) like Visual Studio. The [documentation](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/ExternalProject.html) explicitly notes for which parameters generator expressions are allowed.

Comment: I'm not capable of understanding cmake documentation. Call me stupid if you like.

Comment: Well, CMake's generator expressions are not the ones which can be easily started with. But if you want some example, then you need to be **more specific** about your problem: which exact parameter(s) of ExternalProject are needed to be dependent from configuration in your case, what exact values you want to assign them in the particular configuration and so on. Otherwise there is a little chance that a particular answer will be useful for you: There are tens parameters of ExternalProject which accepts generator expression and that expressions my represent many things.

Comment: "_I'm not capable of understanding cmake documentation. Call me stupid if you like._" you're not stupid. but maybe you lack imagination and/or motivation.